# Can selenium python work good at background while I am doing other processes on main page?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

I am running some test scripts and while it is running at the background I want to do my other jobs on excel or another web page? But sometimes I got same errors since the selenium can not find the specific field to click? What can be the reason? Is it not working well at the background?

Comment: If you could include the code that gives error. And attach error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run selenium concurrently while i am working on other projects i just run it in a headless mode, that tends to work most of the time. 
The thing is that you have to have completed the building of the script before you do this otherwise debugging could be a nightmare if you are new or fairly new to selenium web-driver

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I have checked what is headless mode and it works better now.  Just a more question, what should I do if I want to close the web driver while it is running , maybe I will realize a problem and want to close it immediately. Thanks again

Comment: usually i just do a keyboard interrupt on the terminal with `ctrl c` to kill the process. it works every time for me.

Comment: ctrl c can stop the script but , can it close the web driver which is running at bacground?

Comment: when the script stops the web-driver terminates as well

Answer (score 0):

Generally it should work just fine, but I have found out, that when test interacts with elements that have the [blur events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) it might get disrupted if you are clicking somewhere else.